# getting 1 item from a list with specific fields using c# csom

Tags: 2013, csom

Hi Guys i'm trying to retrieve a specific item from a SharePoint list using CSOM.  I can get the item but im not sure how to specify multiple fields.

```
var Web = context.Web;
                    var SiteInfoList = Web.Lists.GetByTitle(TitleListSiteInfo);
                    var SiteInfoItem = SiteInfoList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery())[0];
                    context.Load(SiteInfoItem, item => item[FieldName]);

                    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Try `context.Load(SiteInfoItem, item => item[FieldName1], item => item[FieldName2], item => item[FieldName3]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code, which is used to retrive the multiple field values

```
var Web = context.Web;
var SiteInfoList = Web.Lists.GetByTitle(TitleListSiteInfo);
var SiteInfoItem = SiteInfoList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery())[0];
context.Load(SiteInfoItem, item => item[FieldName],item => item[FieldName2], item => item[FieldName3]);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To get the properties of single item:

```
context.Load(singleitem, item => item[FieldName],item => item[FieldName2], item => item[FieldName3]);
```

To get the properties for collection of items:

```
context.Load(itemcollections, singleitem => singleitem.Include(item => item[FieldName],item => item[FieldName2], item => item[FieldName3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and faster approach would be to use CAML query to get specific items with specific fields.
You can follow the below article to achieve that.

[Generic way to use CAML query](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caml-query-to-retrieve-the-items-from-a-list-using-csom1)

You can specify the column in the Caml query by doing:

```
query.ViewXml = "<View>"
                           + "<ViewFields>"
                           + "  <FieldRef Name='" + fieldName + "' />"
                           + "</ViewFields>"
                           + "</View>";
```